# How can I cache paginated queries in Apollo client?

Tags: javascript, caching, graphql, apollo-client

I am executing a paginated GraphQL query with the following variables. The page and pageSize are being passed as variables as follows:

```js
const {data} = useQuery(PAGINATED_QUERY, {
    variables: {
        page: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
    }
});
```

Now when I navigate to the second page, the data changes and displays the second page. When I navigate back to the first page however ApolloClient deems this query to be cached because it already executed the query with the same variables. However it still returns the data from page 2.
I assume that's because they use one "cache" where both queries write to, regardless of their variables.

Now there's a Github issue here:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/5659

This is the exact issue I have, but there's no solution except setting the fetchPolicy to 'no-cache' which makes no sense to me.

Is there a way to seperate cached results by variables? I don't want to turn off the cache because of this, but I need serverside paged queries.